# Javascript/html how can i use asyn.js in my array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, async.js

okay just a simple question I am using a JavaScript like so to create an array from textbox.
can any body show me how to implement the async.js eachsreies function for each item in the array I just need an example of how I would use async.js eachseries function in my javascript.
I basicall want to execute a little function for eachseries and wat for callback before next item in array is used

```
<script src="js/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="js/async.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function textareaToArray(t){
    return t.value.split(/[\n\r]+/);
}
function showArray(msg){
    for(i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        // something per item

    }
    // the old code
    // document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = msg.join("&#013;");
}
</script
```

Comment: Do you actually have any code in the loop that is asynchronous, and if not, what would be the point ?

Comment: when using anyfunctions within this code i.e a document write in the loop sections this is asynchrounous hence the reason I am asking I am trying to send an array in series using async.js

Comment: document.write, and just about any other function you can stick in that loop is synchronous, with the exception of setTimeout/interval, ajax and webWorkers, that's why I'm asking why you would need a library specifically built for asynchronous behaviour ?

Comment: basically what I want to do is send a string to my function and wait for the function to finish before using the next item do you know how I can achieve this I am new to javascript so actually knowing what to ask for is hard I just need to know how to make an async function I think so that the array only uses one item at a time until the function completes then it can move to the next item in the array I hope you can help me

Comment: That's exactly what it does by default! There is only one thread, so any function *has* to complete before the next one starts, the only exception would be, as previously stated, if you are using ajax etc. inside the loop. Show us the code, and be specific about the problem, and we can probably help.